# what can be done juju for wordpress users? How To Work with it?

Tags: juju, wordpress

Is Juju important for online shop? How to use it? Especially for wordpress users... I just hear that Juju is associated with wordpress.

What is Juju deploy Wordpress?
[(Archived) Redeploying OMG!Ubuntu Onto the Cloud With Juju](http://web.archive.org/web/20140209000443/http://www.jorgecastro.org/2012/03/18/redeploying-omg-ubuntu-onto-the-cloud-with-juju)

Answer (score 2):

From [Ubuntu Juju | Deploy](https://juju.ubuntu.com/deployment/) page:

> Juju manages your systems architecture as services in the cloud. It is a simple client/server application that bootstraps an instance to create and control the rest of your environment. You can use it through a GUI or from the command-line, scale in all directions and easily move your environment between clouds.

It's not related directly to shopping or [Wordpress](http://wordpress.com/), but you can use it to deploy a wordpress blog (check the tutorial below).

`juju deploy wordpress` is a command-line interface (CLI) command which instructs Juju to deploy a new instance (VM) in the cloud, using the settings defined in your Juju "environment". The equivalent operation in [Juju GUI](https://jujucharms.com/) can be by dragging and dropping a charm, directly from your browser.

For more info check:

- [Juju Documentation](https://juju.ubuntu.com/docs/), including a "Getting Started" tutorial.
- [Juju Features](https://juju.ubuntu.com/features/)
- [Juju GUI Demo](https://jujucharms.com/)
- [Install Juju](https://juju.ubuntu.com/install/)

You can find a lot of answered questions here about [Juju](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/juju).
The source, bugs and other info [can be found on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju-core/).